# Amazon Linux LAMP with php 5.5

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I installed PHP 5.5 on my Amazon Linux VPS via the [instructions here](http://webtatic.com/packages/php55/).  The CLI is working fine.

I also had apache already installed and running via the `httpd` package.  It was running without any issue.

I see that there is no `mod_php` in the list of available modules.  Now when I try to restart `httpd` I get the error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 222 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: symbol SSLeay_version, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference

I've looked up parts of this error, and the general advice seems to be to run

```
yum update openssl
```

However, when I run this I just get:

> No packages marked for update

When I run `install` instead of `update`, I get:

> Package 1:openssl-1.0.1e-4.55.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>   Nothing to do

I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: It's definitely a version mismatch. You could always compile PHP yourself to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `php55` package in Amazon's repositories depends on `httpd24`, not `httpd` (which is 2.2). Using the more recent version of Apache should resolve your issues.

```
$ repoquery --requires php55
/bin/sh
httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
httpd24
...
```

Comment: Perfect; this is just what I needed.  As a followup question how can I get php working with apache now?  `yum install mod_php` says there are some conflicts; I'm not sure if there is a way around that

Comment: You really shouldn't use CentOS/RedHat instructions for Amazon Linux. They're similar, but not the same. `php55` is the package you want. `yum install php55` installs both PHP 5.5 and Apache 2.4 and includes `mod_php` as part of that process. Stock Amazon Linux has **no** package named `mod_php` - if you see one in `yum search` you've got extra repos enabled.